# CSS opacity transition fade in one line at a time

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use transitions to change the opacity and fade in three lines one after another. There is a div on my page with 3 p and strong tags and I am trying to fade in each line after about 2 seconds with .5 seconds in between. Here is a fiddle with just the div and css I am trying. I've searched this topic and tried a few variations of css and js, but no matter what I do the lines start out as fully visible, but if I toggle opacity through inspector, it will then transition in and out (without a delay also for some reason). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/7uR8z/5047/

```
<div class=".Index-gallery-item-content-body">  
    <p>
        <strong>Test Line 1</strong>
    </p>

    <p>
        <strong>Line 2 Here</strong>
    </p>

    <p>
        <strong>Awesome Line 3</strong>
    </p>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.Index-gallery-item-content-body p
{
    opacity:0
}

.Index-gallery-item-content-body p:nth-child(1)
{ 
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.Index-gallery-item-content-body p:nth-child(2)
{
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay: 3s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-ou
}

.Index-gallery-item-content-body p:nth-child(3)
{
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay: 3.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-ou
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to work when `:hover`?

Comment: Seems like your fiddle is missing a few things.

Comment: Also, `transition` is [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions). At least for the sake of your SO question, simplify to remove the vendor variants.

Comment: Jake, I want the three lines to show up one at a time when the page loads

Comment: Also, the fiddle was wrong I am correcting now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for animation not transition:

```css
.Index-gallery-item-content-body p {
  opacity: 0
}

.Index-gallery-item-content-body p:nth-child(1) {
  animation: change 2s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.Index-gallery-item-content-body p:nth-child(2) {
  animation: change 2s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

.Index-gallery-item-content-body p:nth-child(3) {
  animation: change 2s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

@keyframes change {
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Index-gallery-item-content-body">
  <p>
    <strong>Test Line 1</strong>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Line 2 Here</strong>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Awesome Line 3</strong>
  </p>
</div>
```